# IBM CPLEX C++ concert technology - Infeasible solution

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I am using the ILP approach for one of my research problems. Initially formulated the ILP using mathematical programming (.mod), it works fine. But while compiling the c++ code of the formulated ILP using concert technology is showing the error "Infeasible" for the same example. Here I used the IBM CPLEX ILP solver.

The code part which is creating the problem is listed below.

```
**ILP.mod**

//declaration

dvar boolean o_st[range_op][range_cyc][range_dpu];   // 3D boolean decision variable

// Constraint

C1: forall (i in range_op)
  {
    sum(j in range_cyc, k in range_dpu) o_st[i][j][k] == 1;     
   }
```

```
**ILP.cpp**

//declaration

   Numbool3D o_st(env, n_op);             
   for (int i = 0; i < n_op; i++)
   {
      o_st[i] = Numbool2D(env, n_cyc);
      for (int j = 0; j < n_cyc; j++)
      {
         o_st[i][j] = IloBoolArray(env, n_dpu);
      }        
   }

// Constarint

IloExpr exp3(env)
   for (int i = 0; i < n_op; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < n_cyc; j++)
      {
         for (int k = 0; k < n_dpu; k++)
         {
            exp3 += o_st[i][j][k];           
         }               
      }
      Model.add(exp3 == 1);      
   }
```

For a particular example, I am getting the output for the same parameters while using the ILP.mod file. But while compiling the ILP.cpp file using the concert technology, the solver is not providing the solution. Please help me in this regard. I am facing problems, especially with the constraint specified above.

Comment: Do you know that you can call OPL model from C++ through C++ / OPL APIS ?

Comment: No. Please guide me to do that. Please provide the information about this if possible

Comment: You keep on adding to exp3. It should be reset before the j loop.

Comment: Please suggest me the modification in the CPP code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a model that works fine in OPL I would encourage you to call this OPL model from C++ and you can do that with OPL / C++ APIs

Example in CPLEX_Studio2211\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\cpp

In mulprod.cpp you will see

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    IloEnv env;

    int status = 127;
    try {
        IloOplErrorHandler handler(env,cout);
        IloOplModelSource modelSource(env, DATADIR "mulprod" DIRSEP "mulprod.mod");
        IloOplSettings settings(env,handler);
    settings.setWithWarnings(IloFalse);
        IloOplModelDefinition def(modelSource,settings);
        IloCplex cplex(env);
        IloOplModel opl(def,cplex);
        IloOplDataSource dataSource(env, DATADIR "mulprod" DIRSEP "mulprod.dat");
        opl.addDataSource(dataSource);
        opl.generate();

        if ( cplex.solve() ) {
          cout << endl
                << "OBJECTIVE: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << opl.getCplex().getObjValue()
                << endl;
            opl.postProcess();
            opl.printSolution(cout);
            status = 0;
        } else {
            cout << "No solution!" << endl;
            status = 1;
        }
    } catch (IloOplException & e) {
        cout << "### OPL exception: " << e.getMessage() << endl;
    } catch( IloException & e ) {
        cout << "### CONCERT exception: ";
        e.print(cout);
        status = 2;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "### UNEXPECTED ERROR ..." << endl;
        status = 3;
    }

    env.end();

    cout << endl << "--Press <Enter> to exit--" << endl;
    getchar();

    return status;
}
```